# LINQ - How to do partial searches on multiple criteria using NHibernate.LINQ

Tags: linq, linq-to-nhibernate, dynamic-linq

I have a search page where a user can enter multiple cities seperated by a comma and we need to get all the real estate properties where the city is one that is entered in the search criteria. For instance the user will enter something like this

cities = Dallas, Austin

The query I have works fine if the user enters a full city name

var cityList = new List{"Dallas", "Austin"};
var properties = Reporsitory.AsQueryable
    .Where(x=> cityList.Contains(x.City))
    .ToList();

However if I just enter Dal, Aus it does not work. How can I make these partial searches work. Is Dynamic LINQ the only answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var cityList = new List{"Dallas", "Austin"}; 
var properties = Reporsitory.AsQueryable 
.Where(x=> cityList.Contains(y => x.City.Contains(y)).ToList();
```

try to search inside the string, i hope it works

Comment: That didn't work. Contains doesn't like the lambda expression. I used Any instead of that but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know specifically for nHibernate, but Linq to SQL does support this:

```
.Where(x=> x.StartsWith("Dal"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var properties = Reporsitory.AsQueryable().Where(x => cityList.Count(c => x.StartsWith(c)) != 0);
```

Or replace StartWith to Contains...